# How can I change a GWT ListBox to a TextBox?

Tags: gwt, textbox, listbox

I have a GWT ListBox and I want to change it to a TextBox when a value is chosen. How can I do that considering that I am using an uibinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add both elements to layout and change visobility as required. pack the two in a composite for easy management.